# Plotly Table: Vertical align text in cells

Tags: matplotlib, plotly, plotly-python

How can I vertical align text inside [Plotly Table](https://plotly.com/python/table/) cells? I can successfully set the height:

```
go.Figure(
    data=[
      go.Table(
        cells=dict(
          height=50,
        )
      )
    ]
)
```

This looks awful:

[image: Table with text sticking on top of cells]

Answer (score 1):

I have searched in several forums and all I've found is you can do it either  [adding paddingBottom to the styles of the cell](https://community.plotly.com/t/the-way-to-align-text-vertically/49225) or [migrating all your table from Plotly to Dash](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-vertically-align-cells-in-a-table-plotly-graph-objects/65437)